# .ToList() throws exception of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
private void BindDataGridDetails(string p)
{
    var allClients = new List<DataLayer.Client>();

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
    {
        allClients = entities.Clients.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        allClients = entities.Clients.Where(m =>m.CompanyName.Contains(p)||m.ContactPersonName.Contains(p)).ToList();
    }

    allClients = entities.Clients.ToList();

    var finalClientList = allClients.Select(v => new
    {
        v.UserId,
        v.MobileNumber,
        v.Designation,
        v.CompanyName,
        v.ContactPersonName,
        EmailAddress = v.User.EmailAddress,
        status = v.User.Status.Name
    }).ToList();

    Gdview.DataSource = finalClientList;
    Gdview.DataBind();
}
```

Following is the required db table

`User(id,statusid,emailaddress)`

`client(id,userid,designation,mobilenumber,companyname,contactperson)`

`status(statusid,statusname)`

Comment: is it a good thing or bad thing?

Comment: Either that is not your real code, or `finalClientList` is not `null`. `ToList()` *never* returns `null`.

Comment: But then it shows me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Leo its obviously a bad thing ...dats y i posted the question

Comment: @user3189414 If it throws an exception, that's completely different from returning `null`. Please edit your question to reflect the actual problem you're having.